# Getting user entries from a Form based on Genshi Template

Tags: forms, templates, plugins, trac, genshi

I'm trying to write a Plugin for Trac.
I've succeeded to export variables contents from my request (process_request) 
to my template ...but I still having problems doing it in the other way : how to catch the information taped by the user ?

```
<form name="input" action="" method="POST">
    Configuration : <input type="text" name="configuration" value ="$my_var" /> <br /><br />

    <label for="file">URL:</label>
    <input type="text" name="file" id="WillPosted" value="This text will be changed by the user"/>      

    <input type="submit" name="SubmiT" value="Browse" /><br /><br />
```

So how can I catch the content of  the input form with the id="WillPosted" ?
Notice : actual problem is in **IRequestHandler** methods from Trac !

Any Idea ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking about the common web-UI interaction

- my_var --> template with input field 'file' and default value 'This will ..'
- user input to field
- submission by POST request

How to get (changed) new value of input, right? If so, you explained it rather complicated.

And I'm wondering, if you don't know about [trac-hacks.org](https://trac-hacks.org/wiki/), probably the most authoritative source of Trac plugin code on the planet - much more working examples to look at than needed here.

Anyway, the key is reading the return value(s) from `reg.args` dict like so:

```
from pkg_resources  import resource_filename
from trac.web.chrome  import ITemplateProvider, add_stylesheet


implements(IRequestHandler, ITemplateProvider)

# IRequestHandler methods

def match_request(self, req):
    # Any condition evaluating to True will fire the second method.
    return req.path_info == '/<your_path>'

def process_request(self, req):
    "Demo how to interact with your template."

    # Check, if you'r really processing the right request by target matching,
    # and only act on input of authorized users - as an added suggestion/option.
    if req.path_info.startswith('/<your_path>') and req.authname != 'anonymous':
        # Check for request type.
        if req.method == 'POST':
            # Ok, go pock for the new value now.
            value = req.args.get('file', 'default_value')))
            # Now go, process it, store it, even redirect away, if you're done.

            # Fallback for Trac 0.11 compatibility included.
            referer = req.args.get('referer') or req.get_header('Referer')

            # Steer clear of requests going nowhere or loop to self
            if referer is None or \
                    referer.startswith(str(req.abs_href()) + '/<your_path>'):
                referer = req.abs_href()
            req.redirect(referer)

    # Still there, so that's the initial call or anonymous user, hey?
    # So let's prepare information for displaying the template ...
    data = dict(my_var='any_string_or_number')

    # Take the env obj from self, if needed.
    env = self.env
    mod = MyOwnSecondaryModule(env)
    if mod.can_do_something:
        data['my_var'] = mod.do('better')
    # Why not apply an own style?
    add_stylesheet(req, 'your_plugin/most_famous_style.css')

    return 'your_template.html', data

# ITemplateProvider methods

def get_htdocs_dirs(self):
    """Return the absolute path of a directory containing additional
    static resources (such as images, style sheets, etc).
    """
    return [('your_plugin', resource_filename('your_plugin_pkg_base_dir', 'htdocs'))]

def get_templates_dirs(self):
    """Return the absolute path of the directory containing the provided
    Genshi templates.
    """
    return [resource_filename('your_plugin_pkg_base_dir', 'templates')]
```

Questions on using various Trac extension point interfaces? See the authoritative wiki documentation [on the subject](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracDev/PluginDevelopment/ExtensionPoints) as well!

Comment: Dude that is exactly what i needed !!!
value = req.args.get('file', 'default_value')
I knew about trac-hacks.org ... but I got lost there to be honest
and this is my first plugin ...thanks a lot !